# Why snapchat logo won't show on my footer?

Tags: html

I build my first website and I put it on a free host and domain (bookhouse.bookhouse.ml). The footer is ok on the local server (xamp), but when is on the online server the snapchat logo won't display. I can't understand why?

```
<div class="center_footer">
    <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/" target="_blank"><img class="logo_footer" src="snapchat.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" ><img class="logo_footer" src="fb.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="logo_footer" src="instagram.png"></a>               
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img class="logo_footer" src="twitter.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: check if your image is there or named in lowercase

Comment: Did you check to see if the online server has that snapchat.png image? It just looks like it can't locate the image

Comment: @Munim yes i checked.Name is the same.I can't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @pavger yes image is there with the same name,same type of image .

Comment: try a different name for the image

Comment: @Munim i have changed name to snap.png ,still the same problem.It looks like this server dont like snapchat.I have upload a snapchat image with format .jpg but still the same problem.It's making me crazy.Thanks for replay bro

Comment: Image is corrupt, re-upload it or use a different one.

Comment: I removed id,replaced but still the same problem @Munim

Comment: try @J.Afarian's solution, may be she is right, free hosting providers blacklist some words you cannot use in filenames.

Comment: i think this free host don't like snapchat logo .If i set fb logo in the place of snapchat logo and is ok

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue recently trying to upload an icon named snapchat.png / snap.png with the same web host you're using (Infinity Free).

It's going to sound weird, but I re-saved the icon and named it ghost.png and it worked. I have no idea why, but no matter what I did I could not get the snapchat icon to show when I named it snapchat or snap. I tried multiple file types, and re-saved it several times but nothing worked until I renamed it something unrelated.

Comment: i renamed it to ghost.png but still the same problem.But yesterday i renamed it with 'a.png' and it works .When i saw later it still the problem.I can't understand.

Comment: So it's currently named a.png and it was working, but has now broken? Right now on your website it's ghost.png so it's possibly reverted back for some reason. Try re-uploading the a.png if that one worked. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I didn't just re-name the existing file on my server. I completely deleted it, re-named the local one on my PC and uploaded it again with it's new name.